# Time stuck in 24h mode after installing from OEM (loki 0.4.1)

Tags: release-loki

I noticed a very annoying bug after completing a fresh OEM installation. After booting and setting up a user profile from the oem-config, it seems that some of the date and time packages are getting removed.

Now the time won't switch from 24h to 12h. I even tried to change the settings in dconf but had no success.

What am I missing?

If I do a normal installation, everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: Dismiss saying that Wingpanel, tzdata, libboost-date-time1.58.0 and python3-dateutil were not installed.

I have tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata but still not success.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Had to install wingpanel-indicator-datetime_2.0.2+r223+pkg11~daily from the daily ppa.

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/+sourcepub/8449080/+listing-archive-extra

Everything works now